# UIView on top of UIScrollview, pass through only scrolls, not taps

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableview` with a subclass of `UIVIew` on top of a section of the table, like so:

`-uitable--
|--uiview-|
||       ||
||       ||
|---------|
|         |
|         |
-----------`

The view has the same superview as the tableview, but covers the tableview partially. There are a few buttons on the `UIView`. I want the user to be able to scroll on the view and subsequently move the tableview (as if he were scrolling on the table). But, if he taps a button on the view, I want that tap to register on the view, not get sent down to the tableview. Right now, I am overriding the view's `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method to always return `NO`, which works for the scrolling but has the effect of sending all touches down to the tableview, rendering my buttons ineffective. Is there any way for me to pass down swipe/pan gestures to the tableview but keep the tap gestures?

Thanks,

Comment: Why cant you set that view as a tableHeaderView?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of always returning NO from pointInside, check to see if the point intersects any of your UIButton subviews - and return YES if it does.

```
- (BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for ( UIView* sv in self.subviews )
    {
        if ( CGRectContainsPoint( sv.frame, point) )
            return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

**EDIT: alternate solution**

Per your comment you'd like the user to begin scrolling the UITableView with a touch-down on one of the subview buttons.  To make this work you'll need to make the UIView that contains your buttons a subview of the UITableView.

By doing this the UIView will then begin to scroll along with the UITableViewCells.  To prevent this you need to adjust the frame as scrolling happens, or possibly lock it in place using constraints.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // instantiate your subview containing buttons.  mine is coming from a nib.
    UINib* n = [UINib nibWithNibName: @"TSView" bundle: nil];
    NSArray* objs = [n instantiateWithOwner: nil options: nil];
    _tsv = objs.firstObject;

    // add it to the tableview:
    [self.tableView addSubview: _tsv];
}

// this is a UIScrollView delegate method - but UITableView IS a UIScrollView...
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [scrollView bringSubviewToFront:_tsv];
    CGRect fixedFrame = _tsv.frame;
    fixedFrame.origin.y = 100 + scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    _tsv.frame = fixedFrame;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. This works quite well except for one issue. On a normal tableview with a button, if you start your finger on the button and then scroll quickly, the button action is overrode and the swipe is registered. In the case you mentioned above, if I try and do the same thing, the scroll never gets registered. Is there a way to do this, perhaps by returning NO if the velocity of the scroll is faster than a certain value?

Comment: @KyleRosenbluth - I think I understand what you're after.  I updated the solution to account for this.

Comment: I was going to create an answer but Tom's edit beat me to it. Anyways here's a gist that shows that at work: https://gist.github.com/mnmaraes/3dfae9ed353fe49e9d0b

Comment: @TomSwift I just don't understand why do you say it's still necessary to override pointInside:withEvent:. The Scroll View should be able to pick those scroll gestures inside the view regardless.

Comment: @Murillo - ah, you're likely right.  I didn't test it.  Updating my answer.

Comment: @TomSwift This is perfect! Exactly what I was looking to do. Thanks so much.

Comment: @TomSwift, It seems like you missed one small thing. After I implemented your suggestion, the scrolling was working but the button wasn't responding to the touches. I guess that as other cells are added to the screen, the view falls back in the subview index. By calling `bringSubviewToFront:` on the special view in `scrollViewDidScroll`, I solved this issue.

Comment: @KyleRosenbluth - Sounds great.  Glad you worked it out.